# Write object to file not working

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I have the following code:

```
public static void logMessage(Object msg) {
    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            outputStream.writeObject(msg);
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorPopUp.setMessage( e.toString()).setVisible(true);
        }
    } else {
        if ((logDirectory != null) && (writeLogName != null)) {
            try {
                setWriteFileName(writeLogName);
                outputStream.writeObject(msg);
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ErrorPopUp.setMessage( e.toString()).setVisible(true);
            }
        } else {
            ErrorPopUp.setMessage("Log file name not set!").setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
private static boolean setWriteFileName(String name)
throws IOException {
    writeLogName = name;

    if (logDirectory != null) {
        try {
            writeLogFile = new File(name);
            writeLogFile.createNewFile();
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(
                    writeLogFile)));

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    } else {
        ErrorPopUp.setMessage("Log directory name not set!").setVisible(true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using this, the File gets created like I expect it to do, but nothing gets written into it.
I'm pretty sure it's something obvious that I'm missing because I'm looking to long at the code ;)
I really would appreciate some advise.

---

**EDIT:**

```
public static void stopLogging() {
    try {
        if(outputStream != null){
            outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ErrorPopUp.setMessage(e.toString()).setVisible(true);
    }

    if(writeLogFile != null){
        writeLogFile.setReadOnly();
    }
    outputStream = null;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to catch an exception if all you are going to do is throw it.  I suspect if you step through this with a debugger it will be obvious to you what the issue.

Comment: Sure you want to log an object and not an string?

Comment: I tried debugging already several times. The exception thing is just kinda placeholder, it gets replaced. Debugging it, it seems to run fine, but nothing is there at the end. Of course I'm closing the stuff. I'll add the code of this now.

Comment: @Friesgaard: yes I am ;) that's why I'm using `outputStream.writeObject(msg);`
Later I simply what to read them back as objects...

Comment: Is the object `Serializable` or `Externalizable`?

Comment: Yes it is :)  I just checked, to be sure...

Comment: although probably not applicable here, this is a solution - fileWriter.write("some text");
fileWriter.flush();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a (static) TRAP! I bet `ObjectOutputStream outputStream` is static too!

Comment: It's static you're right, shouldn't it? The thing is, it's not entirely my code, I'm adding some Stuff to an existing project...

Comment: OK, the thing is, you have only posted 3 static method, hence we cannot reproduce your problem and fix it. If possible, please post a whole class with a `main` which can be run and produces the problem.

Comment: hmm... I'd like to, but it's a part of something else and I#m afraid i'm not allowed to post the hole code... What else could I do, to give you guys more info?
The `logMessage`is called from outside, it's intention is just to gateway to the file. read and write. There is another build in function in this project, which is using this method flawlessly...

Comment: I tell you what else you could do, Beasly. Use the power of copy-paste, make a mock class using the real ones which will reproduce the error for you. There is possibility, that this will lead you to the bug. If still not have a clue, post the mock class here.

Comment: I found it, sooo simple it's embarrassing. With my file path was happening something funny after creating the file. So it changed somehow and the file which got written was somewhere else. Thanks to everyone who gave it a thought. I accept this answer to close it.